# Перемножение строки на число в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как Python 3 интерпретирует перемножение строки на число, например:

```
print("45"*2)
```

Google не помог.

Что это вообще я предполагаю вывод будет 4545 но ещё не проверял

Comment: Не пишите новый вопрос на месте старого. На этот вам ответили - задайте новый.

Comment: Есть кстати приложения-интерпретаторы python для смартфонов. В них можно легко такое проверить. Если было с чего задать этот вопрос, значит было и с чего проверить)

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> print('45'*2)
4545
```

Python возьмет строковое значение '45' и повторит его 2 раза (целочисленное значение). Перемножение `str` на `int` - это повторение `str` значения подряд `int` раз.